# set image resource from android native resources, programmatically

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, imageview

IMAGE adding in the drawable folder, this code work.

XML

```
android:src="@drawable/myImage"
```

JAVA

```
image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.myOtherImage);
```

But,

IMAGE get with android studio when i use drag and drop palette editor :

XML

```
 app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_offline"
```

JAVA

```
image2.setImageResource( ***what code here  for use presence_online ?*** );
```

Answer (score 0):

xml

```
image2.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.presence_online);
```

R if you use android 11.0(R) sdk 30.

Answer (score 0):

for handle Android API above 16 and above 21 use this code.

> imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_profile))